# Benchmarks of JS libraries including YUI 3

Tags: javascript, performance, mobile, yui, libraries

I've been struggling to find performance benchmarks ıncluding the YUI 3 library. I've Googled it for a while now, but can't seem to find any. Have anyone else found any good comparisons, especially between YUI3 and jQuery?

Note that the library will be used on mobile, which means that it would be great to see a comparison between mobile-focused libraries as well.

I've looked at [Taskspeed](http://dante.dojotoolkit.org/taskspeed/), but it only includes YUI 2.7.0...

Comment: To be honest, benchmarks won't give you a lot of information. As far as DOM interactions go, you'll probably get similar results for both libraries. Even if there is a different, most of the time the speed on your app will depend on what you do with the library and not with what the library is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I'm aware that it usually isn't that much of a difference, but it would be good to have some numbers to support the framework decision (if some management folks want it).